# Server redundancy or failsafe for small single office server

Tags: mac-osx, redundancy, mirroring

We run a local server in our office, and have a domain name pointed to it so we can test out sites we build. We also handle some image hosting for clients for emails.

Since it's a single server, if it hangs and is unavailable so are the services we are providing. Where do I start in setting up a modest failsafe mechanism in the event the server goes out - a server elsewhere can pick up some of the slack, even just serving mirrored images or something.

Any ideas or directions or better yet, solutions would be great.
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest starting by moving the "image hosting for clients" off of the machine in your office -- perhaps to a VPS or a 1U box in an inexpensive colo. If your clients are relying on this for production it should be on a production-grade infrastructure separate from your dev/testing box. (I noticed the macosx tag - if you have your heart set on OSX there are places that specialize in Mac Mini colocation at relatively low prices).

Beyond that if the only production role the box has is image hosting you can just mirror it and do a DNS cutover for quick (though imperfect) redundancy. For the development stuff I think regular, verified (restore-tested) backups are your best bet from a cost/benefit standpoint.

Comment: voretaq7 - I like your suggestions, as far as the second options, can you elaborate or give me a direction to research a DNS cutover? I'll look into mac mini colocation options for us. Thanks.

Comment: @Richard - Check out the "DNS Failover" questions on ServerFault ( http://serverfault.com/search?q=DNS+Failover ) for pros and cons of that method...

Comment: I've actually been exploring this option yesterday, which may be a good solution for us. I thin it may work, I'm just trying to figure out why my DNS keeps bouncing back and forth periodically (maybe a new question). Thanks @voretaq7

Comment: I'm gonna give this the answer since it's the direction I am going in. Thanks for your help in this @voretaq7